# create (or copy) table schema using postgres_fdw or dblink

Tags: postgresql, psql, dblink

I have many tables in different databases and want to bring them to a database.

It seems like I have to create foreign table in the database (where I want to merge them all) with schemas of all the tables.

I am sure, there is a way to automate this (by the way, I am going to use psql command) but I do not know where to start.

what I have found so far is I can use

```
select * from  information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'mytable'
```

I added more detail explanation.

1. I wanted to copy tables from another database
2. the tables have same column names and data type
3. using postgres_fdw, I needed to set up a field name and data type for each tables (the table names are also same)
4. then, I want to union the tables have same name all to have one single table.

for that, I am going to add prefix on table

for instance, mytable in db1, mytable in db2, mytable in db3 as in
db1_mytable, db2_mytable, db3_mytable in my local database.

Thanks to Albe's comment, I managed it and now I need to figure out doing 4th step using psql command.

Comment: Methinks you are looking for `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`, but your description is too vague to be sure.

Comment: Ah! right, that is the answer. but it imports all the records. I wanted to have only field (column) names though.

Comment: You still didn't explain what you need so that I can understand it.

Comment: Ah, you want to shard data across several databases and use postgres_fdw and a `UNION` view for that, and you want to automatize the procedure. I suggest that you use declarative partitioning for the latter.